# Centering a Float Left Menu with Unknow Width

Tags: css

I want to the Li Element of the Ul of my menu are in the Center, I tried a lot of methods but it is not going on. Take a look on my css:

```
#menu {
    float: left;
    width: 767px;
    height: 38px;
    margin: 11px 0 0 14px;
    background: url(images/menubg.gif) repeat-x;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
    border: 1px solid #efeff1;
}
    #menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 40px;
    }
        #menu ul li {
            float: left;
            color: #767676;
            height: 18px;
            padding: 11px 0px 11px 0px;
            display: inline;
        }
            #menu ul li a {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color: inherit;
                font-size: 12px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                display: block;
                padding: 0px 23px 2px 23px;
                border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e2;
            }
```

I tried display: inline, text-aling: center, but it doesnt get right.
Thanks a lot in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried this too? http://pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm Or `display: inline-block` instead of `inline`? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dtTdg/

Comment: Yes, but both didnt work... Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `float` and added `inline-block` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtTdg/1/

```
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
```

Comment: OMG, Just Legendary dude, AWESOME, thanks a lot again, it Worded hell awesome, thanks a lot again!

Comment: It might not work on older Explorers though. You can try adding `zoom:1` to `#menu ul li` to fix it.

Comment: Again, epic, it worked just Fine in Internet Explorer. Thanks a lot again!